# Facebook Gameroom

Tags: windows, facebook

Facebook Gameroom application in my laptop doesn't open at all after installation. I used it for a while but suddenly it stopped launching. Application does meet all the minimum software and hardware requirements of my system. No matter how many times I uninstall and reinstall, the application doesn't open at all. Even I restarted the system many times. Do I need to format and reinstall OS? Reporting the same in Facebook is of no use, they won't respond at all. Any advises would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Service Pack 1 on Windows 7, you can search the 32bit or 64bit installation on Microsoft page. When you install SP1, re-install Facebook Gameroom.
Otherwise:
Run Facebook Gameroom, wait for at least 5 minutes for program to get auto-updates if there is any and it should launch 
[my facebook gameroom window appears 3 minutes later after launch]

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to launch:
- Open facebook.com on Firefox browser
- Open the game (any game) with "open in game room" button
- Firefox maybe ask for the correct application. Choose game room.

I have no idea why the direct access icon is not working :(

Comment: You mean pop-ups right ? I've tried all those. It also asks in chrome, IE. Doesn't work. Need to reboot I guess.

Comment: The "firefox" solution was a hack that works at the time this issue was reported. After update a couple of days later the problem disappear.
I don't mean pop-ups. I mean exactly open firefox and do the thing with the special button for gameroom. But this is not necessary now.

Answer (score 0):

Just the internet connection problem. Sorry to trouble.